# What is the cross-browser usability of the PATCH http method?

Tags: http, browser, cross-browser, http-method

Do the majority of modern browsers use it? I run the latest Chrome and Firefox stable builds and they work fine with it. I can't find any information saying that it's 100% ok to use though. I read the [IETF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) document from 2010 about it, but it says "Standards Track" so I'm not sure if that means it's a usable standard.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Yes, browsers support it (in XHR). I think the last one to cause problems was IE8.

(2) It's "standards" as opposed to "experimental", "informational" etc. Isn't that clear enough?

Comment: To add to this, from what I've dug up IE8 doesn't support `PATCH` using the native XHR object, but does support it using the old ActiveX one. If you're using jQuery, [it will automatically work in version 1.11](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13240) and above. There shouldn't be any problems with browsers newer than IE8. This is talking about Ajax obviously.

As far as HTML forms are concerned, `GET` and `POST` are still the only methods supported (for all browsers) due to the HTML spec.